# Publish as major version doesn't shown in the context of a document

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, versioning

I have a misterious problem. 
I have a SharePoint document libary with the following settings:

[image: Settings]

Now i wan't to publish a minor document as majorversion from the context menue. But...
there doens't exist any entry like that.
[image: wrong context]

But I don't know why. Is there an extra setting for that?

Normaly I wanted a context like that:

[image: correct context]

I don't have any customizations in that list or on that page, 
that hide the context. It's a normal document libary.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you made the change to versioning recently, the item needs to be edited first before the changes are made on the content to include versioning.

Comment: But you can also publish a checked in minor version as major. I must not go in the edit mode for the document to publish as major version or am I wrong? Becaus on an other libary this "workflow" works very well.